# Powers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was trying to implement the following function in Haskell

```
p :: Float -> Int -> Float
p x 0 = 1
p x n = x^(p x (n-1))
```

I get:

No instance for (Integral (Float -> Int -> Float)) arising from a use of `fromIntegral'

I am new to Haskell.

Comment: `(^) :: (Num a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a`. Because `Float` is not an instance of the `Integral` type class, you can't use the `^` operator to raise a number to a power whose value is of type `Float`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(**)` can be used to take powers of Float exponents....

`(^)` is only for integral exponents.

```
2 ^ 2.1 --fails
2 ** 2.1 --works
```